# GAE instance is serving on different url

Tags: python, google-app-engine

My google app engine instance is serving on different url than the default's one. Recently I uploaded an GAE project to the newly created instance of code `foo-backend`.

On seeing the serving logs, it shows

```
> /_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs
Saved; key: __appstats__:031500, part: 57 bytes, full: 1452 bytes, overhead: 0.000 + 0.003; link: http://1-dot-foo-backend.appspot.com/_ah/stats/details?time=1479812131572
```

You see, serving url is `http://1-dot-foo-backend.appspot.com` instead of `http://foo-backend.appspot.com`. I want to change this.. Any idea?

Comment: Is this a request log entry or an application log one? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/logs/#request_logs_vs_application_logs

Comment: @DanCornilescu this is the very first entry of my server logs.

Comment: The URL is identifying the exact `foo-backend` service/module version (`1` in this case) that served the request, according to the URL routing rules: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/how-requests-are-routed#routing_via_url. You can't change the format for request logs, but you can add your own (application) logs formatted as you desire. For regular requests the URL matches your desired format if that specific module version is the **default module version**. I haven't yet used the Backend/Endpoints APIs so I can't tell if the same is true for them.

Comment: how to set a version as default? so that it would get  served at `foo-backend` instead of `1-dot-foo-backend`

Comment: By switching traffic to it in the dev console: https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions. Or by using the `gcloud app services set-traffic` cmd: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/services/set-traffic. Unsure if these apply to backend/endpoints APIs, tho. If version `1` is the only module version you currently have deployed it's probably already set as default, thus my suggestion doesn't work in such case.

Comment: @DanCornilescu I deployed the app through appcfg.py file with the `version: 1` text included in my `app.yaml` file. THat's the reason. Works after I deployed the project using `gcloud` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `app.yaml` you have `version: 1`.

To see the 'why' of what's going on here, consider the following scenario: You have version n of your app deployed, with the front-end queuing work for the back-end. You deploy version n+1 and make it the default. But you made a coordinated change between front-ends and back-ends. What now happens if work queued by front-end version n is received by a version n+1 backend? Depending on the change, it might cause mayhem.

The only safe thing to do is to arrange for work queued by a version n front-end to be handled by a version n back-end until all version n work is drained. Meanwhile work queued by a version n+1 front-end get handled by a version n+1 backend. How does this be guaranteed? By encoding the default version at the time the work is queued in the URL.

Comment: ya, without `version: 1`, I can't deploy that particular project to google cloud. Note that I'm using `appcfg.py` file for deployment.