# Google Cloud redirects to different service name

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

For some reason having my defined app engine service name and built URL: myapp.appspot.com redirects to [appversion]-myapp.appspot-preview.com.
Is it ok? Why is this happening? Is there something to do with it?

ADD:
app.yaml

```
runtime: custom
env: flex

resources:
  cpu: .5
  memory_gb: 1.0
  disk_size_gb: 10

manual_scaling:
  instances: 2
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM gcr.io/google_appengine/jetty9

ADD target.war $JETTY_BASE/webapps/root.war
```

Comment: I don't see such redirect, at least not for regular web pages accessed by a browser. Maybe provide more details - it may help identify what's special about your case. Potentially relevant/related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40742829/gae-instance-is-serving-on-different-url

Comment: @DanCornilescu, i have added app.yaml and Dockerfile, might be a problem somewhere here...

Comment: OK, I'm on standard env, that *might* explain the difference...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the new App Engine Flexible Environment beta. The previous version was configured using `vm: true`. Using `env: flex` selects the new beta version that is currently redirected to this temporary domain. From [Domain update](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/upgrading#domain_update):

> Traffic is now served from the `appspot-preview.com` domain instead of
>   the `appspot.com` domain. All traffic from the App Engine flexible
>   environment will be automatically redirected to the new domain. All
>   App Engine Standard traffic will continue to be through `appspot.com`.
>   When the App Engine flexible environment is generally available (GA),
>   users will be able to use the `appspot.com` or `appspot-preview.com`
>   domains for routing traffic.